# How to stop 3-year-old from bouncing in every bed?

Tags: pre-schooler, discipline, safety, manners

My 3-year-old son has the habit of sitting and bouncing in bed. It doesn't interfer with sleeping and napping. He even jumps on the sofa. He does that whenever he enters a room with a bed and when he watches something exciting on TV.

In our home, I just close the doors to my bedroom. But I don't know how to stop him when he's bouncing in my neighbour's bed. He refuses to come with me and they are telling me to let him play.

I fear that my son could get hurt. I feel a little worried since this behaviour is little odd. It's also not nice when he does that in my friend's home. How can I reduce this habit?

Comment: Can you please provide more details, like what you already tried etc.?

Comment: Does it interfere with sleeping/napping? Are you worried about damaging the bed or your son getting hurt? I'm not trying to be obtuse, but I wonder how often it's being done, and why you want to stop it.

Comment: mayne you  could talk to him or what are you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be many factors that are responsible :

- First the size of your house; i am saying this because if your have small apartment and your child spends most of the time in the room with a bed then probability is that he will do most of his stuff on Bed including a lot of jumping and litter.
- probably he is more active and not getting enough outside time to play and jump around so he do that in the house instead.
- He is still very young and at this age jumping is a very exciting sport for them specially if your bed a soft and big.

It's a very normal behavior and many kids do this but you should always have some basic rules and manners inside house.

I would suggest you take him outside more and let him play and do a lot of these things in the playground, make him understand that jumping on the bed is not a good habit.

If your apartment is big then try to make him play in drawing room and hall instead where there is no bed around and observe his activities.

These habits will go as he grows but you should always make him understand what is good and what is not allowed.

Comment: I'd like to add, when you say "Don't jump on the bed", make sure you mean business. If he doesn't listen, physically take him off the bed. Every time. When kids discover they're just empty threats/commands, they tune it out completely. Soon, hopefully, you wouldn't have to physically make him stop. After a while,  hoping some more, you wouldn't even have to tell him.

Comment: In addition to being firm on the "no jumping" rule, in my house, it also helped to have a designated bed to jump on. This is a mattress on the floor which the kids sleep on. They love jumping on it, it has kept them active, and they also learnt some cool flips! If they jump on any other bed/sofa, I just remind them they can only jump on that particular bed, and the behavior is under control.